# GlassFish - Deploy application without restarting the domain

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

I have an application in production and need to update it without bringing down who is using it, because whenever I need to conduct a redeploy the application falls until redeploy be completed, and this can cause me discomfort because the application as I had told in this production.
Is there any way to do this in glassfish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [document that discusses application upgrades and availability on Glassfish](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2426/abdik.html). It may help.

Note: the work associated with creating an environment to support your goal is not trivial.